# How to display data from an array with nested objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to display data from an array with nested objects?

There are a bunch of objects in the array that have nesting, I tried to loop the render, but it didn't help

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Apple",
    fields: {
      title: "iPhone",
      fields: {
        title: "14 pro",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
  {
    title: "Xiaomi",
    fields: {
      title: "phone",
      fields: {
        title: "MI 5",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
];

  const itemsRender = (item, idx) => {
    const key = Object.keys(item).at(-1);
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <p>{item[key].title}</p>
        {!isEmpty(item[key]?.fields) &&
          Object.values(item[key]?.fields).map(itemsRender)}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <>{DATA.map(itemsRender)}</>;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Added the subIdx parameter to the recursive call of itemsRender to provide a unique key for each nested item.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Apple",
    fields: {
      title: "iPhone",
      fields: {
        title: "14 pro",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
  {
    title: "Xiaomi",
    fields: {
      title: "phone",
      fields: {
        title: "MI 5",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
];

const isEmpty = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
};

const itemsRender = (item, idx) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0]; // Use [0] instead of at(-1)
  return (
    <div key={idx}>
      <p>{item[key].title}</p>
      {!isEmpty(item[key]?.fields) &&
        Object.values(item[key]?.fields).map((subItem, subIdx) =>
          itemsRender(subItem, subIdx) // Recursively render nested items
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return <div>{DATA.map(itemsRender)}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Did not work(((

Answer (score -1):

We can pull specific data with "dot" notation. Then using `.map` method to iterate through an array of objects.

Note: just in case I modified the keys to make it more legible.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    brand: "Apple",
    description: {
      phone: "iPhone",
      spec: {
        model: "14 pro",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    brand: "Xiaomi",
    description: {
      phone: "phone",
      spec: {
        model: "MI 5",
        fields: {},
      },
    },
  },
];

export default function Items() {
  return (
    <div>
      {DATA.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>Brand: {item.brand}</p>
          <p>Phone: {item.description.phone}</p>
          <p>Model: {item.description.spec.model}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```